# verbatim problem when exporting dataframe to latex in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, latex

I'm working with Jupyter Notebook and latex exporting. I want to make my dataframes appear as Latex tables when I export to Latex.

I am currently doing a `print(df.to_latex())` to export a dataframe to Latex in the Jupyter notebook. This produces a tabular style Latex table in the output. The problem is that when Jupyter generates the resulting Latex file, it is wrapping the table output in a "verbatim" block, which means that the table just appears as Latex source code in the Latex file instead of an actual rendered Latex table.

Is there a way to disable the "verbatim" block around the latex code when I export in Jupyter? I can manually delete the verbatim block from the Latex code of course, and the resulting table format works just fine, but I was wondering if there is a way to disable this behavior or modify the latex templates that come with Jupyter to prevent this?

**EDIT** Here is an example:

Basically, create a new Jupyter Notebook with the following two cells of input:

```
    # Cell1
    import pandas as pd
    from IPython.display import display  
    data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}     
    df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
    display(df)

    # Cell 2
    print(df.to_latex())
```

Then, export that to Latex. I tried to export it both using the Jupyter Notebook GUI (File -> Download as Latex) and using the command line. For the command line I used this:

```
jupyter nbconvert LatexTesting.ipynb --to latex
```

When converting to Latex, the "display(df)" command ends up being rendered like this:

```
 \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, size=fbox, boxrule=.5pt, pad at break*=1mm, opacityfill=0]
\prompt{Out}{outcolor}{1}{\boxspacing}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
    Name  Age
0    Tom   20
1   nick   21
2  krish   19
3   jack   18
\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

The "print(df.to_latex())" command ends up being rendered as this:

```
    \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\textbackslash{}begin\{tabular\}\{llr\}
\textbackslash{}toprule
\{\} \&   Name \&  Age \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}
\textbackslash{}midrule
0 \&    Tom \&   20 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}
1 \&   nick \&   21 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}
2 \&  krish \&   19 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}
3 \&   jack \&   18 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}
\textbackslash{}bottomrule
\textbackslash{}end\{tabular\}

    \end{Verbatim}
```

The problem is that it is including the "Verbatim" environment around the Latex table which prevents the table from rendering in Latex. It is easy to delete it manually, but I am still curious to know if there is a way to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: could you provide an example of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I found that in order to get the Latex to render properly for a Pandas dataframe, you need to do two things.

First, you need to import Latex:

```
from IPython.display import display, Latex
```

Then, to display the dataframe you can do this:

```
display(Latex(df.to_latex()))
```